# How to thread-safe signal threads to pause in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a bunch of threads running concurrently. Sometimes a thread needs to notify other threads to wait for it to finish a job and signal them again to resume. Since I'm somehow new to Java's synchronization, I wonder what is the right way to do such thing. My code is something like this:

```
private void Concurrent() {
    if (shouldRun()) {
        // notify threads to pause and wait for them
        DoJob();
        // resume threads
    }

    // Normal job...
}
```

### Update:

Note that the code I wrote is inside a class which will be executed by each thread. I don't have access to those threads or how they are running. I'm just inside threads.

### Update 2:

My code is from a crawler class. The crawler class (crawler4j) knows how to handle concurrency. The only thing I need is to pause other crawlers before running a function and resume them afterwards. This code is the basics of my crawler:

```
   public class TestCrawler extends WebCrawler {
    private SingleThread()
    {
        //When this function is running, no other crawler should do anything
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Page page) {
        if(SomeCriteria())
        {
            //make all other crawlers stop until I finish
            SingleThread();
            //let them resume
        }

        //Normal Stuff
    }
   }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `BlockingQueue` instead?

Comment: Threads are only stopped by adding code to them to stop.  You cannot stop/pause a thread externally safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short example on how to achieve this with the cool java concurrency stuff:

*snip* old code doesn't matter anymore with the Pause class.

EDIT:

Here is the new Test class:

```
package de.hotware.test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    private Pause mPause;

    public Test() {
        this.mPause = new Pause();
    }

    public void concurrent() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            this.mPause.probe();
            System.out.println("concurrent");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void crucial() throws InterruptedException {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
                this.mPause.pause(true);
                System.out.println("crucial: exclusive execution");
                this.mPause.pause(false);
            } else {
                System.out.println("crucial: normal execution");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Test test = new Test();
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test.concurrent();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Runnable cruc = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test.crucial();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        ExecutorService serv = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        serv.execute(run);
        serv.execute(run);
        serv.execute(cruc);
    }

}
```

And the utility Pause class:

```
package de.hotware.test;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 * Utility class to pause and unpause threads
 * with Java Concurrency
 * @author Martin Braun
 */
public class Pause {

    private Lock mLock;
    private Condition mCondition;
    private AtomicBoolean mAwait;

    public Pause() {
        this.mLock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.mCondition = this.mLock.newCondition();
        this.mAwait = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }

    /**
     * waits until the threads until this.mAwait is set to true
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public void probe() throws InterruptedException {
        while(this.mAwait.get()) {
            this.mLock.lock();
            try {
                this.mCondition.await();
            } finally {
                this.mLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * pauses or unpauses
     */
    public void pause(boolean pValue) {
        if(!pValue){
            this.mLock.lock();
            try {
                this.mCondition.signalAll();
            } finally {
                this.mLock.unlock();
            }
        }
        this.mAwait.set(pValue);
    }

}
```

The basic usage is to call probe() before each run. This will block if it is paused until pause(false) is called.

Your class would look like this:

```
public class TestCrawler extends WebCrawler {

private Pause mPause;

public TestCrawler(Pause pPause) {
    this.mPause = pPause;
}

private SingleThread()
{
        //When this function is running, no other crawler should do anything
}

@Override
public void visit(Page page) {
    if(SomeCriteria())
    {
        //only enter the crucial part once if it has to be exclusive
        this.mPause.probe();
        //make all other crawlers stop until I finish
        this.mPause.pause(true);
        SingleThread();
        //let them resume
        this.mPause.pause(false);
    }
    this.mPause.probe();
    //Normal Stuff
}
}
```

Comment: OK, there's a lot of stuff here. Are you sure I need all this for my case? Could you please read my latest update and tell me how to modify my code.

Comment: concurrent(...) is the same thing as visit in your case. crucial(...) the same as SingleThread(...). I don't know the framework, but if you have more than one instance of the class you may need to pass a Object to all of them that they can lock on. But let me just fiddle something together.

Comment: I used your code. A couple of times tested and worked fine. However, when I tested in real situation, seems there's some error. It is like:
`Crawler1 -> Probe
Crawler2 -> Probe
Crawler3 -> Probe
...`
Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: are you using the code from your class that I modified?  And you might have to make your SomeCriteria()-method threadsafe.

Comment: i think your general problem is that multiple threads get to be the exclusive thread. you have to make this part threadsafe and you won't get a deadlock. basically what you need to do is to create an "atomic" block in which you get the permission and as soon as you have taken it, make the others don't get it. This could be done via an AtomicBoolean and a getAndSet(value). This will retrieve wheter you are allowed to get the permission to be the exclusive thread and after that set it to false (so it has been taken). But with this you have to care about race conditions when setting it to true.

Comment: If you need more info, you could contact me directly btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StockMonitor extends Thread {

    private boolean suspend = false; 
    private volatile Thread thread;

    public StockMonitor() {
        thread = this;
    }

    // Use name with underscore, in order to avoid naming crashing with
    // Thread's.
    private synchronized void _wait() throws InterruptedException {
        while (suspend) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    // Use name with underscore, in order to avoid naming crashing with
    // Thread's.
    public synchronized void _resume() {
        suspend = false;
        notify();
    }

    // Use name with underscore, in order to avoid naming crashing with
    // Thread's.
    public synchronized void _suspend() {
        suspend = true;
    }  

     public void _stop() { 
        thread = null;
        // Wake up from sleep.
        interrupt();     
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
        final Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (thisThread == thread) {
            _wait();
            // Do whatever you want right here.
        }
     }
}
```

Calling `_resume` and `_suspend` will enable you to resume and pause the `Thread`. `_stop` will let you stop the thread gracefully. Note that, once you stop the `Thread`, there is no way to resume it again. The `Thread` is no longer usable.

The code is being picked from a real world open source project : http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/file/b17c0fbfe37c/src/org/yccheok/jstock/engine/RealTimeStockMonitor.java#l247

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that you are creating the thread yourself. I can't do that. I've updated my question. How can I do something similar then?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori Can we do this- Create a `daemon thread` and ask other threads to `Join` it?

Comment: I think I wasn't explaining my problem good enough. Please read the 2nd update. I think it will clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait() and notify()

thread waiting:

```
  // define mutex as field
  Object mutex = new Object();

   // later:
   synchronized(mutex) {
        wait();
   }
```

notify the thread to continue

```
   synchronized (mutex) {
        notify();
   }
```

Comment: Could you please give me a quick example?